# Using Github GUI for Mac and git from the terminal

Tags: macos, git, github

Is there any problem using both the GUI version of Github *and* the terminal version interchangeably? For instance, If I start a coding session using the GUI, then need to do something that I only know how to do from the command line. Then switch back to the GUI.

Are there any issues with that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both the GUI version and the command line (terminal) version can be used interchangeably. I use both myself on a Mac and haven't encountered any issues thus far.

Comment: But the GitHub for Mac doesn't use the original git program, as far as I'm aware it uses an objective-c port called **libgit2** (http://github.com/libgit2/objective-git). For example, you need to actually install git seperately from GitHub for Mac in order to use the command line. Does this not hinder workflow as you are essentially working on two different local databases - via two different versions of git?

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with this, I do it all the time.  The GUI is nice because it allows you to see all the newest changes very easily and well as do quick commit + sync.  But I use the terminal for finer control like forcing a branch checkout

```
git checkout -b newBranch
```

I also switch to the terminal when I want to stash changes I have made and am not ready to commit so I can go to an older branch to fix something that is needed immediately (stashing stack is awesome!)

So yea, there is nothing wrong with this approach at all.  Sounds like you know what you are doing, the terminal just give you finer control.